# unable to match and replace using sed in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file named `params.txt` and the content in the file will be
`%test(dir='/home/spread',src=tab1,tgt=tab1,sch=xyz);`

I need a shell script where i will be passing these 4 parameters while calling the script. File `params.txt` has to be updated with whatever i pass.
For example,

```
params.sh '/tmp/category' emp emp hr
```

Before replacement:

```
%test(dir='/home/spread',src=tab1,tgt=tab1,sch=xyz);
```

After replacement:

```
%test(dir='/tmp/category',src=emp,tgt=emp,sch=hr);
```

I will be calling the script multiple times and the parameters need to be updated with whatever is passed while executing the script.

Comment: it is a sas based script that I need to call using shell script. I am using a macro to call the parameters that are mentioned in the file. I tried using "sed" to replace but i was not sure how to use regex to parse only required fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are simply looking for

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "%%test(dir='%s',src=%s,tgt=%s,sch=%s);\n" "$@" >params.txt
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much tripleee. what does "$@" donote?

Comment: The command-line parameters, as a properly quoted list. Google allows you to [search for "dollar-at bash"](https://www.google.com/search?q=dollar-at+bash) these days; my top hit is [this canonical answer from Stack Overflow.](/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)